# How to stop asking for the credentials while deploying reports in ssrs 2008

Tags: ssrs-2008

While deploying reports I am getting login prompt asking for the User Name and password. I have tried providing all possible id and passwords but no use. I can access both the Report manager url and ReportServer url but if I start deploying reports through SQL Server Business Intelligence development studio I am getting the above mentioned prompt. Please let me know how to avoid this.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure that the server on which you are trying to deploy the Reports, you must be under the group which has the following Role assigned.
Browser, ContentManager and Publisher.

Answer (score 2):

goto Start menu ->Microsoft SQL Server 2008->Configuration tools ->select Reporting services configuration manager ->Connect Report server ->Select Database from the left side options -> Current Report server Database -> Click Change Database ->Choose Existing server Database ->Test the connection ->Next -> Select Report Server as Report server Database.

And goto Select Database from the left side options ->  "Current Report server Database Credentials" ->select Authentication type as integrated security and Test connection -> select Authentication type as Service credentials.

I hope it will resolve the problems

Answer (score 1):

Best verification is to make sure you are deploying the new reports to your report server link. And not to the link which corresponds to the report manager. I was running across the process of deploying reports after ages, and I observed this problem when the report server target link is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

I use VM for SSRS development.. and it's not a member of the domain where the SSRS Service lives.

I was able to easily eliminate prompts when deploying reports.. by setting up a LOCAL user account on the SSRS server that used the same username / password as what I was using in my VM.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, but this worked for me: When deploying from SQL Server Business Intelligence Development Studio, you must be running it as Administrator. ie. Right-Click and select 'Run as Administrator'.

This is possibly because if you are not running it with elevated privileges, then it can't do the Impersonation to login to the server.

Answer (score 0):

Using web services URL in TargetServerURL instead of Report Manager URL.

Goto Reporting services configuration manager, connect SSRS server then go to "Web service URL" in right hand side you will find a link like as http://server//reportingServer. Copy the url.

Now open Business Intelligence Development Studio. open SSRS project.

Goto Project menu and click on properties, in property page Paste copied URL in TargetServerURL. Now Rebuild the project and Deploy. Credential will not appear and Deploy succeeded.

Answer (score 0):

When moving (deploying or copying) an RDL file from one location (development) to another (production) the report may loose track of it's shared data source, at which point the data set will replace the original  node with a new node that instructs SSRS to demand credentials.

In the report that is persistently demanding credentials if you right-click in solution explorer and select 'view code' the .rdl will open in an xml reader window. If your mark up contains a reference that looks like:

```
<DataSources>
    <DataSource Name="YourDataSourceName">
      <ConnectionProperties>
        <DataProvider>SQL</DataProvider>
        <ConnectString>Data Source=<i>your-server</i>;Initial Catalog=<i>your-db-name</i> </ConnectString>
        <Prompt><b>Enter a user name and password to access the data source:</b></Prompt>
      </ConnectionProperties>
      <rd:SecurityType>DataBase</rd:SecurityType>
      <rd:DataSourceID>e2f9f97c-GUID-GOES-HERE-395c383c1da2</rd:DataSourceID>
    </DataSource>
  </DataSources>
```

If this is what you find in the xml/rdl this is likely your problem.

1. Make sure you have a Shared Data Source that works as expected, you may have to build a new report based off of this that does not prompt for credentials.
2. In a report that does NOT ask for credentials, open the RDL using 'view code' option.
3. Select the relevant xml  node (under ) and copy the node, it should look something like:

> ```
> <DataSource Name="YourDataSourceName">
>       <DataSourceReference>YourDataSourceName</DataSourceReference>
>       <rd:SecurityType>None</rd:SecurityType>
>       <rd:DataSourceID>19f0a78a-<b>GUID-GOES-HERE</b>-0e277b3b153f</rd:DataSourceID>
> </DataSource>
> ```

4. In your target report replace the  node with the one you copied.

(worth noting that when you change the 'rd:SecurityType' from 'Database' to 'None' you are NOT removing security, you are merely passing responsiblity for authentication from the report's dataset on to the shared datasource. (Security is born by the connection rather than the query)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, it was due to the wrong spelling of the TargetServerUrl in report project properties, make sure that it meet the same name in the Report Server Configuration Manager:

[image]