# Deploying SSRS report on local host--- login dialog box appearing repeatedly

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2

I created SSRS report and that gets the information from SQL Server 2008 R2 (TargetServerURL-http://localhost/ReportServer). Now, I am trying to deploy this report on localhost, when I do that I see a login dialog box (Reporting services login) repeatedly. I tried to give my machine credentials and sql server credentials but nothing worked. What can be the solution to this issue. Can anyone help me with this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps [this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4859571/how-to-stop-asking-for-the-credentials-while-deploying-reports-in-ssrs-2008) can be of help? I think you may need an account on `localhost` with the correct roles/permissions, when ReportServer has the default settings.

Comment: Also, see my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12005778/377930) regarding 'Run as Administrator'.

Answer (score 0):

Also you need to set the URL of the SSRS instance as a trusted site in the users browser. Depending on your configuration, you may also have to configure Kerberos Authentication, rather the default (NTLM)