# SSRS Report ask for Login when deploy

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

For this i searched related links like  [How to stop asking for the credentials while deploying reports in ssrs 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4859571/how-to-stop-asking-for-the-credentials-while-deploying-reports-in-ssrs-2008) etc.but didn't find any satisfactory answer.

I have a problem in deploying my report in BIDS on my local server because there's a Reporting Services Login box that keeps prompting whenever I deploy my report, asking for Username and Password on Browser. I provide both windows and SQL Server credentials but didn't work.

[image]

**Browser Error** 
[image]

Comment: how you deploying your report ???  using which tool ??

Comment: are you putting TargetServerURL like this "http: // SERVERNAME/reportserver" ??

Comment: refer this site http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/246/bids/

Comment: Dear go to the URL http: //alpha/Myreport in browser and upload your report from there..

Comment: you are deploying at http: //muhammad/reportserver make sure this link working or not

Comment: it showing that report server database not exist put http://muhammad/reoprtserver in Internet Explorer and check